# Django: Display current locale in a template

Tags: django, localization, internationalization

I need to embed the current locale in a Django template's output (as part of a URL to be precise). I know that I can access the current **language** as `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` if I `{ load i18n }` but is there a similar way to access the current **locale**?

I suppose I could use `to_locale()` in the view logic and put it in the context for the template, but I'm looking for something more generic that might be part of the Django framework itself. Is there such a syntax?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I solved this by including code below in the template

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
```

and the variable `LANGUAGE_CODE` has the value you want (see also [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates) for an example usage).

Comment: LANGUAGE_CODE isn't the same as locale name, as stated in the question. Compare "en-gb" with "en_GB". They're in different standard formats.

Comment: How is this any different from just using `{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}` as stated in the question? I get the same output in both cases.

Answer (score 14):

You might want to [write your own context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), which would call `to_locale` and automatically populate the context with the result -- it would just be something like this.

```
from django.utils.translation import to_locale, get_language
def locale(request):
    return {'LOCALE': to_locale(get_language())}
```

Comment: I need to add that the context processor will only work when using RequestContext. I'm not so I'm going for the custom template tag instead.

Answer (score 3):

I thought of implementing my own [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) that would simply output `to_locale(get_language())` but the answer above is easier to implement so I like it better.