# How to get user's locale name in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to get the user's current locale name as part of some internationalization proccess of a specific plugin, in the format ll_CC (like pt_BR, en_US, pl_PL), as described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/ **inside** of a Django template. I've been able to get only the language code so far (which is in the format pt-br, en-us, pl) using:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANG %}
Your language is: {{ LANG }}
```

But I need the locale name. How can I get this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6361858/django-display-current-locale-in-a-template)

Comment: I didn't try this link that you mentioned, but I also found it before.. Anyway I found my own solution: As I'm already using Django to translate the pages, I just marked the place that I need to get the locale to be translated as well, for example, I have in the template `//connect.facebook.net/{% trans "pt_BR" %}/all.js#xfbml=1` and then I just need to translate this with the rest, and will change automatically as Django detects the browser's language.

Comment: what an ackward salution when django gives the tools you need

Comment: @NT3RP I looked at that, but the accepted answer appears to not answer the question at all.

Comment: @BrunoFinger I'm working with a code base where a previous developer has used roughly the same hack. I was hoping to find a cleaner solution, but if I don't I'll probably copy that hack to even more locations.

Comment: Well, this question is more than 2 years old and, actually rereading it now I feel somehow embarrassed of this solution I used. I'll see if there's another way, maybe with Django's current version it's possible to do this in a more correct way now.